# Getting a phantomjs fontconfig error when generating PDF from lambda function using highcharts-export-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, phantomjs

I am setting up a lambda function which will generate reports using 
highcharts-export-server, when running locally it's working fine but when deployed in AWS lambda it is generating a report but without fonts and getting [error] phantom worker 40 error — Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file.

Tried setting environment variable pointing to fontconfig file.

[error] phantom worker 40 error — Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following environment variable to your Lambda function:

```html
FONTCONFIG_PATH=/var/task/fonts
```

This enables Lambda to find your configration file in the project "fonts" subfolder:

```html
/var/task/fonts/fonts.conf
```

Your font files should be copied to the "fonts" subfolder also, or that will be the next error you run into; the AWS Linux AMI provides DejaVu fonts by default:

```html
/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/*.ttf
```